# Why is `!!(a||!a)` always true?

Tags: boolean, boolean-logic, boolean-expression

I'm a Java rookie and in School we got some homework. I shall explain boolean terms but I don't understand one of them.

The question is

> Why is this expression always true?
>
> ```
> !!(a||!a)
> ```

I understand the part in the brackets but what do the two exclamation marks in front of it?

If the first a = true  --> !a = not true --> !! ( double negation = true?) a = true and the second !a = not true --> !!a = true --> !!!a = not true

and if I'm right , why is this expression alsways true? That beats me.

Could any of you explain that to me?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: `a || !a` is always true because it's either `true || false` or `false || true`, then `!!true` = `!false` = `true`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, `!! expression` cancels out: it’s the same as `expression`, because the negation of a negation is the original value.

So we’re left with `a || ! a`, which is a disjunction. So the result is `true` if at least one of the sub-expressions `a` or `!a` is true.

And lastly, `a` is true if `a` is true (duh). And `! a` is true if `a` is false. Thus, regardless of the value of `a`, the overall expression is true.

Comment: It's good to point out that even though `!!` cancels out, they are widely used for type conversion in different languages.

Comment: @PooyaEstakhri
"different languages?"
Which ones? I can only think of JavaScript.

Comment: @Nirvana It’s much less common but to a lesser extent the same idiom is used in other languages. I’ve seen it in C code, PHP (IIRC) and even R. It’s bad code in all of these languages.

Comment: @Nirvana and also python even though  not operator in python is `not`, and not `!`

Answer (score 2):

### If "a" is TRUE add "!a" is FALSE

Knowing `a` is **true** and `!a` is **false** (*! is for the negation*; in this case, *negating true* -> **false**)

If `a||!a` means **true** or **false**, and from that expression you get **true**...

You can see it like this:
**`!!(true)`**.

What is the result of a double negation? **True**.
Then, **true(true) = (aka a||!a)**, which finally makes your expression `!!(a||!a)` **always true**.

---

### If "a" is FALSE and "!a" is TRUE

Knowing `a` is **false** and `!a` is **true** (*! is for the negation*; in this case, *negating false* -> **true**)

If `a||!a` means **false** or **true**, and from that expression you get **true**...

You can see it like this:
**`!!(true)`**.

What is the result of a double negation? **True**.
Then, **true(true) = (aka a||!a)**, which finally makes your expression `!!(a||!a)` **always true**.

Answer (score 0):

!!(a||!a)

Using one of the axioms of Boolean Algebra, a double negation cancels out everything.

so it would be equivalent to say `(a||!a)`.

Assuming, we set `a = true`; many programing languages use lazy evaluation of conditional statements, the conditional statement would evaluate to true and execute whatever was inside the body of the if statement.

If we set `a = false` , then the right hand side of the conditional statement becomes true... as `!a` is the inverse of a meaning if `a == false, !a == true`.